# multi value grouping with xslt 2

Tags: xslt-2.0

For starters my apology for the title, but I do not know a good way to describe my problem. A code sample will therefore make things more clear.

Assume I have following xml tree :

```
<root>
<node>
<value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
<value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
<value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
</node>
<node>
<value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
<value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
</node>
<node>
<value xml:lang="en">Some Other English Content</value>
<value xml:lang="fr">Some Other French Content</value>
<value xml:lang="de">Some Other German Content</value>
</node>
<node>
<value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
<value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
<value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
</node>
<node>
<value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
<value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
</node>
</root>
```

So basically there are various nodesets, with a number of localized strings , and I want to group these sets based on the content. Node 1,2,4 and 5 are about the same topic, but not all strings might be available in all locales, so i can not really use a reference string (say English, as it's not available in node 5). Node 3 contains different content, so it should be part of a different group.

Sounds probably pretty complex, but this is the result I like to get (using xslt 2) :

```
<values>
<group>
    <value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
    <value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
    <value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
</group>
<group>
    <value xml:lang="en">Some Other English Content</value>
    <value xml:lang="fr">Some Other French Content</value>
    <value xml:lang="de">Some Other German Content</value>
</group>
</values>
```

Any idea on how to best deal with this ? Note that I can have up to 40 different languages in a node, and can have hundreds of nodes in a file, so resources can become an issue also.

Comment: What happens if there is an element like `<node><value xml:lang="fr">Some Other French content</value><value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value></node>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your requirement fully but I wrote some code that first tries to fill up `node` elements with `value`s for the missing languages and then to group on the filled elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

<xsl:variable name="languages" as="xs:string*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values(root/node/value/@xml:lang)">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="node/value" use="concat(@xml:lang, $sep, .)"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <values>
    <xsl:variable name="filled" as="element(node)*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="fill"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$filled" group-by="string-join(value, $sep)">
      <group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="value"/>
      </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </values>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node" mode="fill">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="this" as="element(node)" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$languages">

      <value xml:lang="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of
          select="if ($this/value[lang(current())]) 
                  then $this/value[lang(current())]
                  else (key('k1', 
                            concat($this/value[1]/@xml:lang, $sep, $this/value[1]),
                            $main-doc)/../value[lang(current())])[1]"/>
      </value>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I needed some order to fill up the elements so I sorted on the distinct `@xml:lang`, I am not sure you want that. With that approach the output for the input you have posted with Saxon 9.5 is

```
<values>
   <group>
      <value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
   </group>
   <group>
      <value xml:lang="de">Some Other German Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="en">Some Other English Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="fr">Some Other French Content</value>
   </group>
</values>
```

I am also not sure which strategy is the intended one to fill elements (see also the comment I posted). In the end I decided to key the `node/value` elements on the concatenation of `@xml:lang` and their content, then when filling up elements where a language is missing I simply match on the first `value` child a `node` has. So that basically means if some `node` has a first `value xml:lang="foo"` with contents `bar`, the match is simply on that language `foo` and contents `bar` and we copy over the `value` contents for the missing language.

If you don't want the sorting and you can live with the order of the initial sequence of attributes then you can omit the sorting, the stylesheet then is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

<xsl:variable name="languages" as="xs:string*" select="distinct-values(root/node/value/@xml:lang)"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="node/value" use="concat(@xml:lang, $sep, .)"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <values>
    <xsl:variable name="filled" as="element(node)*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="fill"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$filled" group-by="string-join(value, $sep)">
      <group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="value"/>
      </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </values>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node" mode="fill">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="this" as="element(node)" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$languages">

      <value xml:lang="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of
          select="if ($this/value[lang(current())]) 
                  then $this/value[lang(current())]
                  else (key('k1', 
                            concat($this/value[1]/@xml:lang, $sep, $this/value[1]),
                            $main-doc)/../value[lang(current())])[1]"/>
      </value>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the output is as you asked for:

```
<values>
   <group>
      <value xml:lang="en">Some English Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="fr">Some French Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="de">Some German Content</value>
   </group>
   <group>
      <value xml:lang="en">Some Other English Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="fr">Some Other French Content</value>
      <value xml:lang="de">Some Other German Content</value>
   </group>
</values>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. In the end it didn't really work out well in my real live content, but you got me on the right path for sure.